# How to pass password into pkcs12 conversion using openssl module?

Tags: bash, scripts, openssl

**script.sh**

```
certKey=$(openssl rand -hex 70)

openssl pkcs12 -export -out fullchain.p12 --passin pass:$certKey -inkey .../privkey.pem -in .../fullchain.pem~~
```

I when calling this script the certKey is not passed in, and system asks me for the pkcs12 password.

Comment: How can some string that you just  randomly generated be the passphrase for your *input* files? O.o

Comment: @muru I store the $certKey in a database later in the script

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[openssl Documention](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssl/pkcs12.1ssl.en.html)

> -passout arg pass phrase source to encrypt any outputted private keys with. For more information about the format of arg see the PASS PHRASE
> ARGUMENTS section in openssl(1).

```
certKey=$(openssl rand -hex 70)

openssl pkcs12 -export -out fullchain.p12 -passout pass:$certKey -inkey .../privkey.pem -in .../fullchain.pem
```